# How to solve the exponential equation $\exp({\frac{b+a}{a}u})+\exp({\frac{b}{a}u})=w$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equation
$$\exp\left({\dfrac{b+a}{a}u} \right)+\exp\left({\dfrac{b}{a}u} \right)=w$$
where $u$ is unknown and $w$ is known?

Comment: How would one solve $x^{b/a}(x+1)=w$ in general? I don't think one would; in the very special case $b/a=5$, we need Bring radicals, so the situation looks grim for a general method here.

Comment: (err, technically that should be $b/a=4$...)

Comment: If you divide the entire equation by $e^{\frac{b}{a}u}$, you would get $e^u + 1 = \omega\left(e^u\right)^{-\frac{b}{a}}$. Analyzing these two functions would give you an idea of the *existence* of such solutions, although it is hard to tell which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerically.

Letting $x=e^u$ (as anon does in a comment) the equation becomes $x^{b/a}(x+1)=w$ and then $$x^b(x+1)^a=v$$ where $v=w^a$. Even if $a,b$ are positive integers, making this a polynomial equation, there will be no analytic solution if $a,b$ are relatively prime and $a+b\ge5$. So you would have to resort to numerical methods, such as Newton's Method, which generally depend on a knowledge of Calculus.

[Added 9 July]
Even in the case $a=2$, $b=1$, the equation $$e^{3u/2}+e^{u/2}=w$$ becomes $$x^3+x=w$$ on setting $x=e^{u/2}$, and while there is a formula for solving that one, an analogue of the quadratic formula but for cubics, that  formula is not generally included in the school curriculum nowadays. You won't have any trouble finding it on the web, if you want it - just look for "cubic formula".

I suppose the best way to solve your equation is to find some software designed to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lambert-Tsallis function https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046

and write the analytical solution in 2 different ways. One of them will obey the original equation.

1. $x=\bigg (\frac{W_{\frac{r-1}{r}\big(rw^r\big)}}{r} \bigg)$ with $r=a/b$ and $u=log(x)$
2. $x^r=\bigg (\frac{W_{\frac{r-1}{r}\big(rw^r\big)}}{r} \bigg)$ with $r=b/a$ and $u=\frac{a}{r\cdot b}log\bigg (\frac{W_{\frac{r-1}{r}\big(rw^r\big)}}{r} \bigg)$.

The first formula is simpler and for results tested all values of $x$ were obtained using it. However, i am sure that some parameters will cause that only values found of second solution will obey original equation, instead of the first one.
For comparison, there are some values
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & w & W &  u\\
2 & 1 & 10 & 8 & 1.3862943 \\
2 & 10 & 10 & 0.267475619264026 & 0.290711052696032\\
-2 & 5 & \pi & -0.320142581143897 & -0.222698084474618
\end{bmatrix}

$a,b,w \in R$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{\frac{(b+a)u}{a}}+e^\frac{bu}{a}=w$$
$$e^{\frac{(b+a)u}{a}}+e^\frac{bu}{a}-w=0$$
$u\to\frac{a}{b}\ln(t)$:
$$t+t^{\frac{a}{b}+1}-w=0$$
$$\frac{t}{w}+\frac{1}{w}t^{\frac{a}{b}+1}-1=0$$
$t\to wx$:
$$x+w^\frac{a}{b}x^{\frac{a}{b}+1}-1=0$$
$$x+-\left(-w^\frac{a}{b}\right)x^{\frac{a}{b}+1}-1=0$$

The equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. The equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)